# NDSolve output as input to another NDSolve

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration

I want NDSolve to solve the problem $$y'(x)=0, y(0)=1, x\in[0,1] $$ and then use $y(x)$ to solve  $$z'(x)=y(x), z(0)=0, x\in[0,1] $$.

This is a toy model of the real problem.

In the real problem the equations cannot  be solved   analytically nor in the same NDSolve.

Here is my attempt:

```
    (*First ODE gives y as output*)

s = NDSolve[{y'[x] == 0, y[0] == 1}, y, {x, 0, 1}]
yy[x_] := Evaluate[y[x] /. s]
Plot[yy[x], {x, 0, 2}, PlotRange -> All]

(*Second ODE must use y as input*)

s2 = NDSolve[{z'[x] == yy[x], z[0] == 0}, z, {x, 0, 1}]
zz[x_] := Evaluate[z[x] /. s2]
Plot[zz[x], {x, 0, 2}, PlotRange -> All]
```

Mathematica cannot manage this as it "is neither a list of replacement rules nor a valid dispatch table, and so cannot be used for replacing".

Comment: I'm curious as to why you can't just concatenate the arguments of the individual `NDSolve` calls (i.e., something like `NDSolve[{y'[x] == 0, y[0] == 1, z'[x] == y[x], z[0] == 0}, ...]`.  I'm happy to take this as a constraint, but I just can't envision the problem that wouldn't allow it.

Comment: The solution should only be considered valid within the interval defined by the `NDSolve`, i.e., `{x, 0, 1}`. Consequently, plotting beyond that range with `{x, 0, 2}` should not be trusted outside the interval `{0, 1}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This maybe?

```
s = NDSolve[{y'[x] == 0, y[0] == 1}, y, {x, 0, 1}]
yy[x_] := Evaluate[y[x] /. s] // First
Plot[yy[x], {x, 0, 2}, PlotRange -> All]

s2 = NDSolve[{z'[x] == yy[x], z[0] == 0}, z, {x, 0, 1}]
zz[x_] := Evaluate[z[x] /. s2]
Plot[zz[x], {x, 0, 2}, PlotRange -> All]
```

Answer (score 3):

*(I see that this is the solution suggested by @Michael, and the OP apparently thinks a single NDSolve can't be used. Perhaps the OP can provide an example showing why a single NDSolve can't be used?)*

Why not just use one [`NDSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NDSolve) (or even better, [`NDSolveValue`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NDSolveValue))?

```
sol = NDSolveValue[{y'[x]==0, y[0]==1, z'[x]==y[x], z[0]==0}, {y,z}, {x,0,1}];
```

Visualization:

```
Plot[Evaluate @ Through @ sol @ t, {t, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I' m a liitle bit to late, but the problem can be solved  very easy using NDSolveValue two times:

```
Y = NDSolveValue[{y'[x] == 0, y[0] == 1}, y, {x, 0, 1}]  (* 1st solution Y[x] *)
Z = NDSolveValue[{z'[x] == Y[x], z[0] == 0}, z, {x, 0, 1}](*2nd solution Z[x]*)
```

plot both results:

```
Plot[{Y[x], Z[x]}, {x, 0, 2}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]